# Interpretation of log ratio as dependent variable and independent variables

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, logarithm

I am estimating two linear models. In the first, the outcome variable is a log ratio equal to log(measure at t/measure at t-1) and the independent variable is logged. In the second, the outcome variable is measured in percentage points from 0 to 100 (i.e., 1, 2, 3 and so on), and the independent variable is a log ratio again equal to log(measure at t/measure at t-1). The variables that are log ratios generally reflect pretty large changes and so don't really approximate percentage change. I am therefore keeping these in log units, so .2244 instead of 22.44.

How do I interpret these models substantively? For the first model, would I interpret it in the same way that I would a log-log model? And for the second, would I interpret it in the same way I would a linear-log model?

Thanks!

Comment: You appear to try to define a series $Y_t$ in terms of a series $X_t$ and the series $X_t$ in terms of $Y_t,$ which makes your situation incomprehensible.  Maybe there are some typographical errors in your formulas?

Comment: Thank you for responding. I have edited my question to be clearer. I hope that helps!

Comment: To further clarify: these are four different variables.